# Why no Ofeqs between 11 and 16?

Tags: earth-observation, military, reconnaissance-satellite, israel, ofeq-spacecraft

Wikipedia's [Ofeq; Launch History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ofeq#Launch_history_%5B3%5D) lists Ofeq 1 through 11 and then 16. It does not mention a 12, 13, 14 or 15. Were they so stealthily launched that nobody knows about them, or skipped, had non-Ofeq based names (see Ofek-8 below), or something else?

> **Ofeq**, also spelled **Offek** or **Ofek** (Hebrew: אופק‎, lit. Horizon) is the designation of a series of Israeli reconnaissance satellites first launched in 1988.

---

The Wikipedia section references Space Launch Report's [Shavit](http://www.spacelaunchreport.com/shavit.html) ([Archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20191221151143/http://www.spacelaunchreport.com/shavit.html) copy) and also has pages for these individuals:

- [Ofek-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ofek-7)
- [TecSAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ofek-8) "**EL/M-2070 TecSAR**, also known as **TechSAR**, **Polaris** and **Ofek-8**"
- [Ofek-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ofek-9)
- [Ofek-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ofek-10)
- [Ofek-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ofek-11)
- [Ofek-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ofek-16)

Related:

- [The strange orbit of Ofeq 11 - how does it (actually) do this?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18295/12102)
- [Why use a retrograde orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36163/12102)
- [How are military satellites with (apparently) classified TLEs still showing up on sat map websites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18300/12102)