# Who was the first left handed astronaut (or cosmonaut) to orbit retrograde?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, spaceflight-firsts, retrograde-orbit

Most astronauts are right handed, and most crewed orbits are prograde. Who was the first retro lefty?

Comment: Have there been _any_ crewed retrograde orbits? I'm not seeing [any orbital inclinations over about 65°](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36295/22816)

Comment: Re-researching; Yes, there have... just not around Earth.  The Apollo missions' Lunar orbits are all retrograde.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With notovny's hint, I determined that retro lefty was [Jim Lovell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Lovell), flying in a retrograde orbit around the moon on [Apollo 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_8).

Several photos of Lovell signing autographs show him holding a pen in his left hand, such as this one from the Wisconson Aviation Hall of Fame:

[image: Photo of Jim Lovell wearing a suit seated at a table signing something; pen is visible in his left hand.]

Comment: Can you provide a reference that Jim Lovell is a lefty? He is often listed with other lefty Apollo astronauts, but these lists often contain errors. For instance, Buzz Aldrin is often described as a lefty despite published pictures of him signing with his right hand.

Comment: Dozens of search engine hits for "left handed astronaut" and "left handed jim lovell", but I can't find anything particularly authoritative. (Some of them say "Buzz Aldrin was a native left-hander but changed to use his right hand", by the way.)

Comment: I found [a photo of Lovell and Gene Kranz signing photos](http://moonpans.com/signed/Jim-Lovell-Gene-Kranz-signed-photo.htm); Kranz has a pen in his right hand, Lovell has a pen in his left.

Comment: (Aldrin punches with his right, anyway.)

Comment: Russell ... Bingo !

Comment: after [shamelessly sharpening the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMKg2.jpg) it looks like the shortened title on the spine of the book to Lovell's left is something like "Oshkosh 90" and looks like it might be this item in Amazon.com: [EAA Oshkosh 1990: Gateway to Aviation](https://www.amazon.com/EAA-Oshkosh-1990-Aviation-Approximately/dp/B000FPCN0K) my point being that the title of the book is not a mirror image, indicating this image wasn't inadvertently reversed during the publication process, meaning that it's good evidence.

Comment: Uhoh ... Good one! One "thumbs up" and a bonus Hardy Boys Award !

Comment: I found enough different Lovell-signing-things photos that I figured they couldn't all be flipped.